# Problems Accessing DOM from Browserify Module

Tags: javascript, html, svg, browserify

I have an html document with a large set of SVG elements in it. Certain elements need to have event handlers attached to them, which I would like to do in a dedicated browserify module (it's a game for a programming class). My HTML markup generally looks like this:

```
<!-- Health Stuff -->
<g id="Health_Plus">
    <rect x='72' y='184' width='20' height='20' fill-opacity='0' /> 
    <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="82.223" y1="186.167" x2="82.223" y2="202.167"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="89.723" y1="194.167" x2="74.723" y2="194.167"/>
</g>
<g id="Health_Minus">
    <rect x='74.723' y='210' width='15' height='10' fill-opacity='0'/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="89.723" y1="213.833" x2="74.723" y2="213.833"/>
</g>
<g id="Health_Icon">
    <line fill="none" stroke="#EC1C24" stroke-width="11" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="61.504" y1="128.726" x2="61.504" y2="177.716"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="#EC1C24" stroke-width="11" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="37.01" y1="153.221" x2="86" y2="153.221"/>
</g>
<g>
    <text id='Health_Text' x='40' y='210' font='sans-serif' font-size='25'>10</text>
</g>
```

And my module code looks like this:

```
module.exports = (function ()
{
    // function StatsManager = {};

    function StatsManager ()
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Value for outputting debug code. //
        //////////////////////////////////////
        this.DEBUG = true;

        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Default values for start of game //
        //////////////////////////////////////
        this.startingAttackVal = 5;
        this.startingDefenseVal = 5;
        this.startingHealthVal = 5;

        this.attackCap = 10;
        this.defenseCap = 10;
        this.healthCap = 10;

        this.attackFloor = 1;
        this.defenseFloor = 1;
        this.healthFloor = 1;

        ///////////////////
        // Actual values //
        ///////////////////
        this.attackVal = this.startingAttackVal;
        this.defenseVal = this.startingDefenseVal;
        this.healthVal = this.startingHealthVal;

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Hooks to all the UI buttons in the stats manager //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this.attackPlus = document.getElementById('Attack_Plus');
        this.attackPlus.addEventListener('click', self.AttackPlus);

        this.attackMinus = document.getElementById('Attack_Minus');
        this.attackMinus.addEventListener('click', this.AttackMinus);

        this.defensePlus = document.getElementById('Defense_Plus');
        this.defensePlus.addEventListener('click', this.DefensePlus);

        this.defenseMinus = document.getElementById('Defense_Minus');
        this.defenseMinus.addEventListener('click', this.DefenseMinus);

        this.healthPlus = document.getElementById('Health_Plus');
        this.healthPlus.addEventListener('click', this.HealthPlus);

        this.healthMinus = document.getElementById('Health_Minus');
        this.healthMinus.addEventListener('click', this.HealthMinus);

        this.specialUp = document.getElementById('Special_Up');
        this.specialUp.addEventListener('click', this.SpecialUp);

        this.specialDown = document.getElementById('Special_Down');
        this.specialDown.addEventListener('click', this.SpecialDown);

        //////////////////////////////
        // Assignment of the values //
        //////////////////////////////
        this.attackText = document.getElementById('Attack_Text');
        this.attackText.textContent = this.attackVal;

        this.defenseText = document.getElementById('Defense_Text');
        this.defenseText.textContent = this.defenseVal;

        this.healthText = document.getElementById('Health_Text');
        this.healthText.textContent = this.healthVal;
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.AttackPlus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Attack +1 Clicked"); }
        if (this.attackVal < this.attackCap)
        {
            this.attackVal++;
            this.attackText.textContent = this.attackVal;
        }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.AttackMinus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Attack -1 Clicked"); }
        if (this.attackVal > this.attackFloor)
        {
            this.attackVal--;
            this.attackText.textContent = this.attackVal;
        }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.DefensePlus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Defense +1 Clicked") }
        if (this.defenseVal < this.defenseCap)
        {
            this.defenseVal++;
            this.defenseText.textContent = this.defenseVal;
        }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.DefenseMinus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Defense -1 Clicked") }
        if (this.defenseVal > this.defenseFloor)
        {
            this.defenseVal--;
            this.defenseText.textContent = this.defenseVal;
        }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.HealthPlus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Health +1 Clicked"); }
        if (this.healthVal < this.healthCap)
        {
            this.healthVal++;
            this.healthText.textContent = this.healthVal;
        }
    }


    StatsManager.prototype.HealthMinus = function() 
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Health -1 Clicked."); }
        if (this.healthVal > this.healthFloor)
        {
            this.healthVal--;
            this.healthText.textContent = this.healthVal;
        }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.SpecialUp = function()
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Special Up Clicked.") }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.SpecialDown = function()
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Special Down Clicked.") }
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.IncreaseAttackCap = function(val)
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Increasing Attack Cap") }
        var amt = val || 1;
        this.attackCap += amt;
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.IncreaseDefenseCap = function(val)
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Increasing Defense Cap") }
        var amt = val || 1;
        this.defenseCap += amt;
    }

    StatsManager.prototype.IncreaseHealthCap = function(val)
    {
        if (this.DEBUG) { console.log("Increasing Health Cap") }
        var amt = val || 1;
        this.healthCap += amt;
    }

    return StatsManager();

})();
```

I require my browserify module in a test.js file by calling

```
StatsManager = require('./StatsManager.js');
```

The problem is when I try to test my event handlers by clicking my SVG buttons, nothing happens. No console messages, nothing. However all the values of the text boxes are changed to 5 (different that the HTML markup default of 10). So this means my module has to be accessing the DOM to change those values but for some reason is not attaching the event handlers. Neither I, nor my professor can figure out why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your assignments to `StatsManager.prototype.*` I'm going to guess that you actually want to return an instance of `StatsManager`

```
return new StatsManager();
```

Otherwise the `this` inside your code is going to be global scope (`window`).

Also the `this` inside your click callback functions is going to be wrong I think.

---

The way your code is now, when you get to the lines like this:

```
 this.specialDown.addEventListener('click', this.SpecialDown);
```

The `this` is `window` and does not have a `SpecialDown` function. Using `new StatsManager()` will cause the same function to be run, but with `this` set to the newly created object instance, which inherits from StatsManager's prototype chain.

---

The second problem is that when `addEventListener()` executes one of your callback functions, the `this` context in those functions will be the HTML DOM element that was clicked, and a `MouseEvent` parameter will be passed to the function. You need to do something to capture your `StatsManager` instance in a closure or call the functions on the `StatsManager` instance.

For example:

```
var self = this;
this.defensePlus.addEventListener('click', function(mouseEvent) { 
    self.DefensePlus(mouseEvent);
});
```

or depending on the browser support needs you could use `[Function.prototype.bind()][1]` like this:

```
this.defensePlus.addEventListener('click', this.DefensePlus.bind(this));
```

---

Unlike a lot of other languages, `this` is not the object that owns the function, `this` is the context that the function was called in.

Comment: Thank you so much, your changes fixed the problem! So just to recap, the way it was before, `this` was referring to the DOM whereas now that I have assigned self to this outside of declaring the event handler, this now points to the instance of StatsManager?

Comment: yes, that basically sums it up. Glad you got it working.